# Client Login asp.net mvc error model , How return error model to Index View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, identity

I use identity in mvc project for Authentication, I have two kind of user,
the first one is Admin user has an Login page , and the second is Client user
the Client user login form used in the layout in model , I made partial view 
for Client Login and impeded it in the Layout, When I press Submit button and the data dose not exist( there is no user ) it Should return model message error for user like this

```
ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
            return PartialView("~/Views/Account/_LoginPartial.cshtml", model);
```

the problem is it return me to Partial view that has no layout

How can I return model Error to page that like Home/Index and view model error

this is the Action I post

```
[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ClientLogin(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return PartialView("~/Views/Account/_LoginPartial.cshtml", model);
        }
        var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);
        if (user == null)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
            return PartialView("~/Views/Account/_LoginPartial.cshtml", model);
            //return PartialView("",model);
        }
        if (!await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user.Id))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "You need to confirm your email.");
            return View(model);
        }
        var lang = RouteData.Values["lang"].ToString().ToLower();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
            returnUrl = "/" + lang + "/ControlPanel/Home";
        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);

        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If page have defined layout doesnt matter for model. In your partial page you need to have `@model LoginViewModel` (assumin you are using razor). Then you will have access to model in your view to show model errors.

Comment: try in your view @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.YourPropertyName)